# Student Roles in Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

How can I get a list of students from D2L? I want to get the grades of the students and when I get the classlist, I get both instructors and student marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/enrollments/orgUnits/{orgUnitId}/users/](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-orgUnits-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-users-). This will fetch a paged result set of all the users enrolled in the course offering identified by orgUnitId. Note that you can filter the result set with the `roleId` query parameter; if you know the role ID for students, you can provide that to fetch back just the users in the course with a student role:

```
https://your.lms/d2l/api/lp/1.0/enrollments/orgUnits/6784/users/?roleId=78&{all_auth_qparms}
```

Note that the enrollments API calls require certain role permissions of the calling user context. The calling user account needs 'View User Enrollments' permission, and to have the 'Search for <*rolename*>' permission for the enrolled user roles visible in the output:

- Without 'View User Enrollments', you won't have any permission to query enrollments at all, and you'll likely get a 403 back (no permission, or forbidden).
- If you don't have the 'Search for Student' or 'Search for Instructor' permission (or whatever your local roles are), then although you can *make* the enrollments call, the list of enrolled users you get back will get filtered down to only the roles you can 'Search for'.

---

**Edit**. I've fixed this answer; the default role ID for students was *not* 3 (that's the default OrgUnitID for course offerings, I think). On our test server the default student role ID is '78'.

**Edit 2**. I've added more information about the permissions required to get useful information from the enrollments call.

Comment: I try to use, the following API to get all the roles (from where I can extract the roleIDs), but it returns null, do you know why?/d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/roles/

Comment: Also, when I place the following request, it gives me HTTP 400 error.
https://test-camosun.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/lp/1.0/enrollments/orgUnits/8644/users/&roleId=3?x_a=C4H8vzHXQQuEAPwq1NEwfQ&x_b=X43Zg5tas73hq273CEiBTu&x_c=tYBXv1llHupHpXIsfyBUAJdoTi1pfuXbPEPwafuQRhU&x_d=hb_qmPle6kElChPM2vGvj9e-Rb7q-XEq1Vj8UOfkUKo&x_t=1340644356

And, if I try to place &roleId=3 or roleID=3, anywhere else in the URL, it throws HTTP 403 error.

Any suggestions???

Comment: It's possible that your calling user context has no permission to use the "fetch all roles" API call. I would first try calling the enrollments call without the `roleId` query parameter and see what you get: it's possible your list will be filtered to just the roles you want anyway. You may be able to infer the right roleId to use for just the type of user you want to further filter down to, based on that.

Comment: I applied the appropriate roleId (and without the roleID) and this is what I get.            {
PagingInfo: {
Bookmark: "",
HasMoreItems: false
},
Items: [ ]
}                                                                   I changed my role permissions too.

Comment: It's likely that what you've done is turned on the 'View User Enrollments' role permission for the calling user, but you're missing the appropriate 'Search for <rolename>' permissions you need to see the enrolled users-by-role.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I changed the setting and it worked perfect.